# How to process huge XML file fast? 

Tags: xml, string, performance

I need to develop a program, for posix systems, for parsing an xml file, on average 300Mb, and inserting the data in a relational database.

The time factor is very important, both in developing and running the programm.

I have a certain generic background in C, Ruby, Python and Java, but not enough depth to make a good choice and in depth optimizations.

I would like to know the opinions and experiences of other programmers, also I would like to have an opinion about functional languages.

Many thanks.

Comment: Python and lxml are very efficient for this purpose. Most of the time will be spent on disk/inserting into the DB, so Python should work great.

Answer (score 1):

Proper design would properly matter more than the language. I.e. it's easy to make a design mistake which would negate all benefits of "fast" language.

If you are limited to named languages, - use C or Java and use third-party parser such as [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/). This will save both development time and you from making design mistakes.

Comment: That's interesting, do you think that a properly designed ruby program (for example) would perform better then C ? 

By the way im not restricted to any language, in fact im interested to compare functional languages too.

Comment: Sorry i mean "could" not would, i say because it's some time i don't write C ...

Comment: C is the fastest of them, but also it takes the most time and effort to develop the solution in it.

Comment: @Alessio as I mentioned, it's easy to make a bug (and it's much more easy to do this in C) if you write your own parser. And as you have mentioned that development time matters, reusing third-party parser is a great idea. And Java in this case can make a good balance between speed and ease of development.